# powershell get-hash sha512 output truncates hash output

Tags: powershell, windows-11

I'm using Windows 11 with Powershell in Windows terminal. When I try to get the sha512 of a debian ISO, I get the following frustrating output:

```
PS C:\Users\xdavi\Documents> get-filehash -algorithm sha512 .\debian-11.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso

Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
SHA512          EEAB770236777E588F6CE0F984A7F3E85D86295625010E78A0FCA3E873F78188AF7... C:\Users\xdavi\Documents\debian-11.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso
```

Note the `8AF7...` with ellipses at the end; which is truncated. How do I view the entire thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use parenthesis around the command and paste *.Hash*

```
(Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha512 .\SteamSetup.exe).Hash
C9125B79012E00FC9EE800592DECE583A97756B5F4485C4649F3A11143AFA673B4D386AF256129032064F158186542BCA7DA70CD31770CD7EB4A3176C96E7124
```

Answer (score 3):

pipe the command to `format-list`, and it will display the entire hash. In particular,

```
PS C:\Users\xdavi\Documents> get-filehash -algorithm sha512 .\debian-11.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso | format-list


Algorithm : SHA512
Hash      : EEAB770236777E588F6CE0F984A7F3E85D86295625010E78A0FCA3E873F78188AF7966B53319DDE3DDCAAAA5D
            6B9C803E4D80470755E75796FBF0E96C973507F
Path      : C:\Users\xdavi\Documents\debian-11.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso
```